# extract last number from the right until special character

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm new to excel , example of data that i need extract the `last number` until it found comma "`,`"

```
712044789659787268,"ほんとやめて、視聴者を殺しに来るのは",1.0
```

Result should be `1.0`

i tried `=RIGHT(C1,FIND(",",C1)+1)` but didn't solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(C1,",",REPT(" ",LEN(C1))),LEN(C1)))
```

Comment: Hello, rather than just providing the code, please break down why this works to the user.  That way, other users that might have the same or similar question can follow the logic of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this Formula and it worked.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A18,",",REPT(",",20)),20),",","")
```

This is basically replacing all "," with 20 commas, taking the last 20 characters and replacing the left commas with blanks.

This will output a string. If you want a number just add a `+0` at the end of the formula

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
=RIGHT(C1,LEN(C1)-FIND(""",",C1)-1)
```

It just finds the `",` and displays the rest of the string after its location.